Spring RESTDocs Error: Query parameters with the following names were not found in the request
I'm trying to document the API using Spring RESTDocs on Spring 3.3.2.
However, the following error appears.
Query parameters with the following names were not found in the request: [password, driverId, loginState, regId, deviceDiv]
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: Query parameters with the following names were not found in the request: [password, driverId, loginState, regId, deviceDiv]

And source code here.
@DisplayName("기사 로그인 API")
    @Test
    void checkMatchLogin() throws Exception {
        //given
        given(driverService.driverLogin(
            anyInt(),
            anyString(),
            anyInt(),
            anyInt(),
            anyString(),
            anyString())).willReturn("true");

        mockMvc.perform(
                // when
                RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.post("/api/driver/login")
                    .param("driverId", "2")
                    .param("password", "2222")
                    .param("loginState", "1")
                    .param("deviceDiv", "1")
                    .param("regId", "please_input_gcm_code")
            )

            // then
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(document("driver-login",
                preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                queryParameters(
                    parameterWithName("driverId").description("driverId"),
                    parameterWithName("password").description("password"),
                    parameterWithName("loginState").description("loginState"),
                    parameterWithName("deviceDiv").description("deviceDiv"),
                    parameterWithName("regId").description("GCM Key")
                ),
                responseFields(
                    fieldWithPath("code").type(JsonFieldType.NUMBER)
                        .description("code"),
                    fieldWithPath("message").type(JsonFieldType.STRING)
                        .description("message"),
                    fieldWithPath("data").type(JsonFieldType.BOOLEAN)
                        .description("data")
                )
            ));

    }

I looked up official documents and searched stack overflow, but I couldn't find them.
Is it too basic to ask?
Give them a hand.
Thank you.
Reference check

https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#documenting-your-api-query-parameters

Change Parameters : queryParameters

relaxedQueryParameters : not worked
requestParameters : not worked


If they are query parameters, you should provide them using queryParam rather than param.
